# Nservice bus 3.0 , .Net Framework 4.0 and Msbuild 3.5

Tags: nservicebus

We have a problem with NService bus and .Net framework.
We have a solution with multiple projects.
Old project1 is using .Net Framework 3.5 and Nservice bus 2.6(compiled with .Net 3.5)dll
New project2 is using .Net Framework 4.0 and Nservice bus 3.0 dll

Projects are compiling fine from VisualStudio2010 but failing while building using MSbuild 3.5

We are getting error for the old project1 which is using NSB2.6 when trying to build using .net 4.0 msbuild for the solution.

The only way we think is to move the project2 into a seperate solution.
This seems like an interesting problem and wanted to know if anyone has faced similar issues.

Can Nservice 3.0 be used with .Net 3.5?

Answer (score 3):

NServiceBus 3.0 and later is only supported on .NET 4.0 and greater.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MSBuild 4.0?  If you're building a .Net 4.0 project in Visual Studio, that's what it's using.